# How do I display a validation error properly if my date format is not correct in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, format, date

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I would like to throw a validation error if a user doesn’t enter their date of birth field in the proper format, so I have

```
  def update
    @user = current_user
    begin
      @user.dob = Date.strptime(params[:user][:dob], '%m/%d/%Y')
    rescue ArgumentError => ex
    end
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
```

and I have this in my view

```
      <%= f.text_field :dob, :value => (f.object.dob.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if f.object.dob), :size => "20", :class => 'textField', placeholder: 'MM/DD/YYYY' %>
      <% if @user.errors[:dob] %><%= @user.errors[:dob] %><% end %>
```

However, even if someone enters a date like “01-01/1985”, the above doesn’t return a validation error to the view.  What do I need to do to get the validation error to be returned properly?

**Edit:** Per one of the answers given, I tried

```
@user = current_user
begin
  @user.dob = Date.strptime(params[:user][:dob], '%m/%d/%Y')
rescue ArgumentError => ex
  puts "Setting error." 
  @user.errors.add(:dob, 'The birth date is not in the right format.')
end
if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  last_page_visited = session[:last_page_visited]
  if !last_page_visited.nil?
    session.delete(:last_page_visited)
  else
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
  end
  redirect_to !last_page_visited.nil? ? last_page_visited : url_for(:controller => 'races', :action => 'index') and return
else
  render 'edit'
end
```

And even though I can see the "rescue" branch called, I'm not directed to my "render 'edit'" block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `update_attributes` clears out the errors that you set in the `rescue`.  You should check for errors, and if none, then continue on, something like this:

```
@user = current_user
begin
  @user.dob = Date.strptime(params[:user][:dob], '%m/%d/%Y')
rescue ArgumentError => ex
  puts "Setting error." 
  @user.errors.add(:dob, 'The birth date is not in the right format.')
end
if !@user.errors.any? && @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  last_page_visited = session[:last_page_visited]
  if !last_page_visited.nil?
    session.delete(:last_page_visited)
  else
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
  end
  redirect_to !last_page_visited.nil? ? last_page_visited : url_for(:controller => 'races', :action => 'index') and return
end

render 'edit'
```

Since you `redirect_to ... and return` you can close out the conditional and, if you make it this far, simply render the edit page.

You may also want to add a simple validation to your user model:

```
validates :dob, presence: true
```

This will always fail if the dob can't be set for some other, unforseen, reason.

To get the user entered string to populate the field on re-load, you could add an accessor to the user model for :dob_string

```
attr_accessor :dob_string

def dob_string
  dob.to_s
  @dob_string || dob.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
end

def dob_string=(dob_s)
  @dob_string = dob_s
  date = Date.strptime(dob_s, '%m/%d/%Y')
  self.dob = date
rescue ArgumentError
  puts "DOB format error"
  errors.add(:dob, 'The birth date is not in the correct format')
end
```

Then change the form to set the :dob_string

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :dob_string, :value => f.object.dob_string , :size => "20", :class => 'textField', placeholder: 'MM/DD/YYYY' %>
  <% if @user.errors[:dob] %><%= @user.errors[:dob] %><% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And update the controller to set the dob_string:

```
def update
  @user = User.first
  begin
    #@user.dob = Date.strptime(params[:user][:dob], '%m/%d/%Y')
    @user.dob_string = user_params[:dob_string]
  end
  if ! @user.errors.any? && @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    redirect_to url_for(:controller => 'users', :action => 'show') and return
  end
  render 'edit'
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :dob_string)
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  This indeed routes me to the correct page, but the text field that displays the date (The line beginning with "<%= f.text_field :dob" in my quesiton), does not contain the original incorrect text the user entered.

Comment: @Dave -- Adding `@user.dob = params[:user][:dob]` in `rescue` block may help. This will assign the value as it is to the `@user` model. :)

Comment: Sadly that line, "@user.dob = params[:user][:dob]"" does nothing.  Although there is data in "params[:user][:dob]," which I can see in debugging, after assigning that to "@user.dob," querying "@user.dob" displays no data.  I'm wondering if this has anything to do with the fact that my underlying PostGres column has type date .

Comment: I've edited my answer with a trick to get the string re-populated in the form.  I add an accessor for the string version of the dob, since, as you  suspected, the Date field can't store the malformed date string to return to the user.

Comment: @Doug, Thanks for this well thought out answer.  I'm noticing an issue.  After executing this line, "if ! @user.errors.any? && @user.update_attributes(user_params)", "@user.dob" is set to empty, even though I am successfully setting it to a valid value in the "@user.dob_string = user_params[:dob_string]" line above.

Comment: Sorry about that -- I updated the dob_string= method to call `self.dob = ...`

Comment: Thanks.  Its still not printing the invalid value in teh text field upon an invalid entry, so I'm wondering should this line "@dob_string = dob_s" actually be "self.dob_string = dob_s"?

Comment: No, `self.dob_string = dob_s` would send you into an infinite loop!   ;-)

Comment: Since dob_string is not a persisted attribute on the model, we need to save it in an instance variable so that the view can access it when we render the edit page.

Comment: This is working for me -- I put everything into a [test app and uploaded to GitHub](https://github.com/solipet/dob_test).  If you check that out, `bundle install`, `rake db:create db:migrate` then go into the console and ensure that one user exists, then run the server and point to localhost:3000/user/edit, you will be editing the one user and the date field gets updated with the incorrect string, if one is given.

Try this and let me know if it's not working for you.

Answer (score 4):

Triggering an exception doesn't add anything to the `errors` list. If you just want to tweak this code slightly, you should be able to call [`errors.add`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_validations.html#errors-add) inside the `rescue` block. Something like `@user.errors.add(:dob, 'some message here')`.

Keep in mind that this will only validate the date of birth when using this controller method. If you want to validate the date of birth whenever the user is saved, you'll want to explicitly add the validation to the model. You can write your own [custom validation class or method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations), and there are also some gems that add date validation.

Comment: I tried yoru suggestion (see my edit) but even though I do see the "rescue" branch called in my controller, execution is not dropping down the part where I return to the origina view but instead is going to "Profile updated successfully" as if all the data was entered ok.

Comment: The issue with the code shown in your edit is that calling `update_attributes` will only check the validations that are explicitly defined in the model, and the `begin`/`rescue` block has no connection to that. If you aren't updating any of the other fields besides `dob`, you could check whether `@user.errors` has anything in it and then `save` instead of using `update_attributes`. My leaning would be to add validation inside the model and then use `update_attributes`. Unfortunately, by the time validation runs, Rails will have already parsed the submitted string into a date.

Comment: I'm not understanding what the solution is given your comment here.  Could you edit your answer to include code I can cut and paste?

Comment: My first suggestion in that comment (checking `@user.errors`) is essentially what @Doug suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41369750/7151673. For the model validation (and for this issue in general), it's important to understand that, if your `dob` field is a date field in the database, then ActiveRecord will try to parse a date string on its own. By the time validation runs, the string will already be typecast to a date (or set to `nil` if that isn't possible), and so there's no way to verify the format at that point.

Comment: I think there are some ways to handle this, but I'll need to look into it more. I'll edit later if no one else has gotten something that works.

Answer (score 3):

I would add a validation rule in the model. Like:

```
validates_format_of :my_date, with: /\A\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\z/, message: 'Invalid format'
```

Comment: Agreed on adding a validation rule in the model. This particular rule uses hyphens as separators when the OP seems to want to use slashes. It also will allow certain numbers in the month and date fields that aren't generally considered valid dates, if that matters for the OP's use case.

Comment: Would this validate a date if someone typed in "99/88/0010"?  If so that's not correct because what I listed ("99/88/0010") is not a valid date.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding validation rule in model.

```
  validate :validate_date

  def validate_date
    begin
      self.dob = Date.parse(self.dob)
    rescue
      errors.add(:dob, 'Date does not exists. Please insert valid date')
    end
  end
```

and in your controller update your code

```
...
@user.update_attributes(user_params)
if @user.save
....
```

Comment: This has a couple of problems -- one of which it will validate the date things taht aren't really dates, like "2/29/2017".

Comment: I've changed the code, Please have a look. This might solve your problem.

Comment: Cool.  THis does validate correct and incorrect dates properly, but when I'm returned to my view, the text field (the one " f.text_field :dob" from my question) doesn't contain anything.  Ideally, it should contain the incorrect value the user entered so the user can correct it.

Comment: Seems like there is a logical error in your controller, I have updated code, Have a look.

Comment: @user.update_attributes does invoke "save" so doing "if @user.update_attributes" is equivalent to what you have, but even trying what you have, the invalid date value is not displayed in the text field.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a case where Active Model shines. I like to use it to implement form objects without extra dependencies. I don't know the exact details of your situation but below I pasted a small demo that you should be able to adapt to your case.

The biggest benefit is that you **don't pollute your controllers or models with methods to support profile updates**. They can be extracted into a separate model which simplifies things.

## Step 1: Store `dob` in `users`

Your `users` table should have a column `dob` of type `date`. For example:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.date :dob, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Don't put anything fancy in your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

## Step 2: Add `Profile`

Put the following in `app/models/profile.rb`. See comments for explanations.:

```
class Profile
  # This is an ActiveModel model.
  include ActiveModel::Model

  # Define accessors for fields you want to use in your HTML form.
  attr_accessor :dob_string

  # Use the validatiors API to define the validators you want.
  validates :dob_string, presence: true
  validate :dob_format

  # We store the format in a constant to keep the code DRY.
  DOB_FORMAT = '%m/%d/%Y'

  # We store the user this form pertains to and initialize the DOB string
  # to the one based on the DOB of the user.
  def initialize(user)
    # We *require* the user to be persisted to the database.
    fail unless user.persisted?

    @user = user
    @dob_string = user.dob.strftime(DOB_FORMAT)
  end

  # This method triggers validations and updates the user if validations are
  # good.
  def update(params)
    # First, update the model fields based on the params.
    @dob_string = params[:dob_string]

    # Second, trigger validations and quit if they fail.
    return nil if invalid?

    # Third, update the model if validations are good.
    @user.update!(dob: dob)
  end

  # #id and #persisted? are required to make form_for submit the form to
  # #update instead of #create.
  def id
    @user.id
  end

  def persisted?
    true
  end

  private

  # Parse dob_string and store the result in @dob.
  def dob
    @dob ||= Date.strptime(dob_string, DOB_FORMAT)
  end

  # This is our custom validator that calls the method above to parse dob_string
  # provided via the params to #update.
  def dob_format
    dob
  rescue ArgumentError
    errors[:dob] << "is not a valid date of the form mm/dd/yyyy"
  end
end
```

## Step 3: Use the form in the controller

Use `Profile` in `ProfilesController`:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    # Ensure @profile is set.
    profile
  end

  def update
    # Update the profile with data sent via params[:profile].
    unless profile.update(params[:profile])
      # If the update isn't successful display the edit form again.
      render 'edit'
      return
    end

    # If the update is successful redirect anywhere you want (I chose the
    # profile form for demonstration purposes).
    redirect_to edit_profile_path(profile)
  end

  private

  def profile
    @profile ||= Profile.new(user)
  end

  def user
    @user ||= User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

## Step 4: Render the form with `form_for`

In `app/views/profiles/edit.html.erb` use `form_for` to display the form:

```
<%= form_for(@form) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :dob_string, 'Date of birth:' %>
  <%= f.text_field :dob_string %>
  <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
<% end %>
```

## Step 5: Add routing

Keep in mind to add routing to `config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :profiles
end
```

That's it!